# Can't find my question

Tags: support

I checked the faq - there was an icon for my inbox showing some comments to my question. I couldn't seem to get to them and now the icon is gone. How do I find my question?

Comment: It seems the question was just deleted. With less than 10K rep, you can't see it anymore. Or were only the comments deleted, as Servy suggests?

Comment: It sounds like the comments, or even the entire question, were deleted.

Comment: @DanielFischer If he didn't get a chance to follow the notification he may not know which question the comment was related to, so he wouldn't know if it was deleted or not.  The question title would be in the notification, but if he didn't notice or remember...

Comment: @Servy Yes, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1899259/frank-polan?tab=questions) seems to indicate the question was indeed deleted.

Comment: And if this bothers you, then see/vote for [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted).

Answer (score 8):

Your question was:  **Is there a Windows 7 installer for PHP5.4**

The answer is:
http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4

You indicated that you had trouble Googling it, but [this search](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%205.4%20installer) led me right to it.

In any case, the question was closed as "Not a Real Question" by five community members, and deleted by a diamond moderator.

---

Note that, if you're looking for something really obscure (like "Where can I find a Windows Installer for PHP that looks like a real installer") that doesn't exist, the Stack is really not the best place to ask for it.  The PHP guys on the PHP site are in the best position to tell you why they did it that way.  Or, you can just accept the release on its own terms, read the installation instructions, and get on with it.

Comment: Not on-topic to *this* question, but that page actually doesn't have an installer for PHP 5.4 on it.

Comment: @JohnFlatness: See my edit.